# Polymer, style disabled web-component

Tags: css, polymer, web-component

I have been looking at [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) lately, however I have come up against problems when wanting to re-style the `disabled` state of the `<paper-button>` element from within a regular stylesheet.

```
<paper-button disabled="disabled" ...>
    #shadow-root
        <script>
            :host {...}
            :host([disabled]) {
                ...I want to be able to overwrite styling here...
            }
```

Can anyone help please? I have tried various incantations of ::shadow but I am just hitting my head against a brick wall :>

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Outside of the definition of an element you don't refer to that element with :host, instead refer to it by its tag name.

```html
<script src='//www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js'></script>
<link rel='import' href='//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html'>
<style>
  paper-button[disabled] {
    border: 5px dotted rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2);
  }
</style>
<paper-button disabled>Can't click me!</paper-button>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter & @Winchestro, I was being a n00b :). I was particularly looking at the background style and was missing an !important :< Marking answer by Peter as accepted since he was first.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood the :host selector. It selects the element *itself*, not the content in the shadow root. In order to overwrite it all you have to do is to...just style the button exactly like you'd do it with a regular HTMLElement :)

```
<style>
    paper-button {

    }
    paper-button[disabled]{
        ..overwrite styling here...
    }
<style>
```